# c# send parameters to anonymous thread function

Tags: c#, multithreading, parameters

I am using the next code to open a thread:

```
var thread = new Thread(() =>{  
   /*thread code*/  
});  
thread.Name = "Thread1";  
thread.Start();`
```

I wish to pass an object to the thread function so I tried this approach:

```
var thread = new Thread(() =>(myObject){  
});
```

But this is not working, so you have any idea how to do it?

Comment: `() => () {}` isn't going to work. Always post valid code.

Comment: This is a many times duplicate but more inportantly, you probably don't want a Thread at all.

Comment: Why complicate things by using an anonymous method? What is your reasoning for needing an anonymous method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the object that you want to reference from your anonymous function ahead of your function, like this:

```
var myObject = ... // <<== Define object here
var thread = new Thread(() => {
    Console.WriteLine("My object: {0}", myObject);
    /*thread code*/  
});  
thread.Name = "Thread1";  
thread.Start();
```

C# compiler will automatically capture the `myObject` object in the process of creating the anonymous function, making it available to use inside the function body.

Answer (score 1):

The version you are using is a `ThreadStart` which takes no argument, we have to use a `ParameterizedThreadStart` which takes 1 argument (of type `object`), so the corresponding lambda expression for that delegate would be something like this:

```
var thread = new Thread((arg) =>{  
    //use the arg here ...
});
//then run the thread like this
thread.Start(myObject);
```

Note that the `Start` method has an overload taking one argument allowing you to pass in the actual argument for the thread when running it.